# Read-write lock in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am looking for a good way to implement read/write lock in Perl.
This is needed to synchronize file access from different Perl threads and/or processes on Windows and Unix.
Tried Fcntl::flock which would be perfect for me if it worked as expected. Unfortunately it looks like under stress flock allows to set lock on already locked file in another thread.
Looked into some CPAN modules, but most are implemented with flock.
Next I am planning to evaluate fcntl for Unix and Win32::Mutex for Windows.
This seems like a pretty common task and perhaps I am missing some simple solution.
If you are aware of any, could you please point it out for me?

Thank you!

Comment: hum, `flock` should always allow another thread to obtain a lock, not just "under stress".

Comment: Is it true in case each thread has its own file handle?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock gives more details on how and when an flock can succeed within same process and same or different fd.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear: 'descriptors are treated independently by flock()' and 'A process may only hold one type of lock (shared or exclusive) on a file. Subsequent flock() calls on an already locked file will convert an existing lock to the new lock mode'.

Comment: So, whithin the same process, is it supposed to block one thread when file was locked by another thread via separate file descriptor?

Comment: Oh yes, `flock` works on open files specified by a file descriptor: "Apply or remove an advisory lock on the open file specified by _fd_."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `flock` won't do what you want across threads.

You can implement your own locking using [sysopen](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html), which fails if the file exists when used with `O_EXCL|O_CREAT`.

An example, with child processes competing for a lock

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Fcntl;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

my $lock_file = ".lock.$$";
sub get_lock {
    my ($file, $pid) = @_; 
    my $fh;
    while (not sysopen $fh, $file, O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_CREAT) {
        say "\t($$: lock-file exists ..)";
        sleep 0.5;
    }   
    say $fh $pid;
}
sub release_lock {
    my ($file, $pid) = @_; 
    unlink $file or die "Error unliking $file: $!";
    say "\t($$: released lock)";
}

my @pids;
for (1..4) {
    my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";
    if ($pid == 0) {
        sleep rand 1;
        get_lock($lock_file, $$);
        say "$$, locked and processing";
        sleep rand 1;
        release_lock($lock_file, $$);
        say "$$ completed.";
        exit
    }   
    push @pids, $pid;    
}
wait for @pids;
```

It is better use [File::Temp](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) for the lockfile name but read the docs carefully for subtleties.

Sample output with 3 processes

```
3659, locked and processing
        (3660: lock-file exists ..)
        (3658: lock-file exists ..)
        (3659: released lock)
3659 completed.
3660, locked and processing
        (3658: lock-file exists ..)
        (3658: lock-file exists ..)
        (3660: released lock)
3660 completed.
3658, locked and processing
        (3658: released lock)
3658 completed.
```

---

The `O_EXCL` may be unsuppored under NFS: you must have at least 2.6 kernel and NFSv3 or there will be a race condition. If this is a problem the workaround is to use `link(2)` to obtain a lock. See `man 2 open` (also for other details since `sysopen` uses `open` syscall).

---

To lock only file access, for example

```
sub open_with_lock {
    my ($file, $mode) = @_; 
    get_lock($lock_file, $$);
    open my $fh, $mode, $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    return $fh;
}

sub close_and_release {
    my ($fh) = @_; 
    close $fh;
    release_lock($lock_file, $$);
    return 1;
}
```

These can be placed in a module along with `get_lock` and `release_lock`, with the lock-file name as a package global, for example.

A simple test-driver

```
# use statements as above
use Path::Tiny;           # only to show the file

my $lock_file = ".lock.file.access.$$"; 
my $file = 't_LOCK.txt';    
my @pids;
for (1..4) 
{
    my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";

    if ($pid == 0) {
        sleep rand 1;
        my $fh = open_with_lock($file, '>>');
        say "$$ (#$_) opening $file ..";
        say $fh "this is $$ (#$_)";
        sleep rand 1;
        close_and_release($fh);
        say "$$ (#$_) closed $file.";
        say '---';
        exit;
    }   
    push @pids, $pid;
}
wait for @pids;

print path($file)->slurp;
unlink $file;
```

With `use` statements from the first example and with 3 forks, a run

```
        (18956: "lock"-file exists ..)    # print out of order
18954 (#1) opening t_LOCK.txt ...
        (18955: "lock"-file exists ..)
        (18956: "lock"-file exists ..)
        (18955: "lock"-file exists ..)
        (18954: released lock)
18954 (#1) closed t_LOCK.txt.
---
18956 (#3) opening t_LOCK.txt ...
        (18955: "lock"-file exists ..)
        (18956: released lock)
18956 (#3) closed t_LOCK.txt.
---
18955 (#2) opening t_LOCK.txt ...
        (18955: released lock)
18955 (#2) closed t_LOCK.txt.
---
this is 18954 (#1)
this is 18956 (#3)
this is 18955 (#2)
```

(note that independent processes are fighting for `STDOUT`)

Comment: NFS is the bane of `flock`'s existence, too.

Comment: @mob sigh ... I work over (under) NFS here :(.  There are good things about it of course (but those don't happen so often to me)

Comment: @AndyH  Added specific example for locking file access

Comment: @zdim Thank you! Your solution does not provide exclusive/shared locks function, but I still can use it as a temporary fix and then create a read-write lock based on your code.

Comment: @mpersico  If you mean why I haven't presented it here as a module, it is to make it simpler.  If you referred to CPAN ... first, thank you for nice words.  For one, I am not sure how generally useful it is (at least, it would take more work to make it so); also, it takes work to prepare it for posting there.  But if this is deemed useful I'll be happy to do it!

Comment: The latter. :-) Would have saved many, many people from reinventing the wheel and having it turn out square (me included).

As for "generally useful", do an experiment - modulize it, post it and see how many downloads it gets (and how much email it generated for you).