# Cron job runs multiple times in an available VMs in the same timing

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I have to run a script in cron, where I am keeping cron entry in /etc/cron.d directory.

So here how my cron entry looks like (in `/etc/cron.d/cron_for_abd_list.cron`):

```
30 * * * * /home/usr/vinod/ABD_List/Cron_script_V1.pl  > /home/usr/vinod/ABD_List/LOG/Log_Cron_`date +\%y\%m\%d_\%H`.txt 2>&1
```

So my cron script will be running each hour 30th minute and storing the Logs in `LOG` directory i.e., `/home/usr/vinod/ABD_List/LOG/`

Actually the system is configured in such a way that where this cron will run in 2 servers at a time. Because that is how the environment is configured.

I have hosts called `serv-1-sms` and `serv-2-sms` and when I keep this cron entry in /etc/cron.d/ directory it would trigger in both the hosts at a time.

So, in order to avoid it to run multiple times in same timing I have used a below logic inside a script.

Logic is, when the script starts running (either from `serv-1-sms` or `serv-2-sms`) it will first check for the dummy file `tempfile.txt` in the same directory(`ABD_List`). If it already exists then process will be terminated, else script will continue running and at the end it will delete `tempfile.txt` which is been created at the beginning.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "/home/usr/vinod/ABD_List/tempfile.txt";
if (-e $filename) {
    print "File already exists.. Exiting: $$\n";
    exit 0;
}

system("touch $filename");

...
#executing the rest of the things in the scripts
...

unlink $filename;

print "END\n";
```

This is how I am avoiding collision of running same script at same time.

I this logic is bit weird. If any alternate logic available please suggest me or if we can control this collision in crontab itself that would be more helpful.

Comment: Do the cron jobs get kicked off at the same time on both servers?

Comment: @benjessop Nope. I am using this logic to avoid running it at the same time on both the servers.

Comment: An approach like this is one way.  But this code allows a race condition with perhaps data loss or undefined behavior or such. Instead, you can just open a file (in Perl, not via `system`!) using a [lock](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) and if it's locked already exit. Make sure to read up on this. Here's [an article](https://www.perl.com/article/2/2015/11/4/Run-only-one-instance-of-a-program-at-a-time/) that comes up.  If there's a problem with locking facility on your system here is an example of [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46819735/4653379) around that.